# Cocoa: Prevent NSOpenGLContext flushBuffer from blocking if VSync is enabled

Tags: multithreading, cocoa, macos

I am currently developing a c++ application framework on osx (I am on the osx version right now, will become cross platform) and I ran into the following issue: Basically my application class is entirely event driven. I also wrote my own Timer/Callback (not using NSTimer though and thus only related to my own event loop and not NSApplications) class in c++ that simply adds events to my Applications event queue so that they get fired from the mainthread. Now, I am basically letting one of those timers fire as fast as possible to call my Windows draw function which basically looks like this (pseudocode):

```
void myCocoaWindow::draw()
{
    enableNSOpenGLContext();
    //perform drawing

    //Swap buffers
    [[m_glView openGLContext] flushBuffer];
}
```

Everything works very good aslong as vertical sync is turned off. But as soon as I turn it on, the `flushBuffer` function blocks until the next vertical retrace and thus blocks my whole event loop. 
The following questions result from that:

1. How is the **NSApplication** event loop handling that? if I implement the same behaviour using native cocoa code only, NSApplications event loop does not seem to be affected by the wait for **vertical retrace**?
2. Can I maybe run the draw function in a secondary thread (and thus avoid the blocking inside my event loop)? That would require a threadsafe initialization and access of the appropriate **NSOpenGLContext** though, is that possible?

To clarify question two, I know I can lock all the functions related to the NSOpenGLContext myself, my question is rather if it is safe that nothing else will access the context that I don't have any control over!

Comment: okay, I found http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/OpenGL-MacProgGuide/opengl_threading/opengl_threading.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001987-CH409-SW1 which indicates that it is possible to create a threadsafe version of NSOpenGLContext if you make sure it gets only accessed by one thread at a time. I will check if this can be a solution to my problem!

Comment: Just in case anybody is interested, I have a first simple version that seems to work like a charm.- I am still running all my window code on the main thread (for sake of simplicity) and only create a worker thread if vSync is enabled, that only runs the [m_glView openGLContext flushBuffer]; command. My Timer waits until the call is done, and then reschedules.